# Pass Variable to Nested Resource in Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have the following nested resource definition:

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::resource('employees', 'EmployeeController');
Route::resource('employees.external_training_records', 'ExternalTrainingRecordController');
```

**ExternalTrainingRecordController**

```
public function create()
{
    return view('employees.external_training_records.create');
}
```

**views/employees/show.blade.php**

```
<a href="{{ route('employees.external_training_records.create', $employee) }}">Create External Training Record</a>
```

**views/employees/external_training_records/create.blade.php**

```
<div class="card-header">{{ $employee->name }}</div>
```

Laravel is not liking that in the `views/employees/external_training_records/create.blade.php` it is calling an undefined variable on `$employee`

How do I pass the `$employee` to the nested resource's create page?

Answer (score 0):

it can fix your problem. add a variable name to *route* function.

```
route('employees.external_training_records.create', ['employee' => $employee]);
```

**ExternalTrainingRecordController**

same to here

```
public function create(Employee $employee) // add parameter with type hint
{
    return view('employees.external_training_records.create', ['employee' => $employee]); // add parameter in array
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You pointed me in the right direction. I needed to add `App\Employee $employee` as the parameter to the create function on the Controller. I also needed to query the database for the object, and pass that to the view. Thanks!